# New items not being added to TFS Pending Checkins in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I created a new VS2013 solution today and checked into TFS. I noticed that when I add new items to a project it does not get included in my TFS Included Changes list. I've tried added with Add New Item, by running Entity Framework's `add-migration` command, and generating files with Resharper. I reviewed the settings but nothing stood out to me, although I'm not well versed with TFS settings. What could be causing this?

Comment: Is you Solution/Project "Bound" to source Control, Have a look in File, Source Control, Advanced, Change Source Control...

Comment: That was it. Please enter as an answer and I'll accept it. Not sure how the bindings broke...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new Solution, you need to "Bind" it to source control.

There are three ways to do this:

You can do this from either the menu:

- **File, Source Control, Advanced, Change Source Control...**

or, if you have the "Source Control - Team Foundation" menubar you can click this button:

[image: Change Source Control]

or, you can use "Add Solution to Source Control..." when you right click on your solution in "Solution Explorer":

[image]